# Почему NULL записывается в поле как текст?

Tags: laravel

Почему при таком раскладе-

```
$buyer->ref_username = NULL;
```

в поле нулл записывается как текст а не как нулевое значение?

Answer (score 0):

сработал маленький null   почему не знаю)))